# Can an interjection act as both an independent and dependent clause?

Tags: grammar

As an independent clause:

> Hello! My name is John.

As a dependent clause:

> Hello, my name is John.

Perhaps I'm missing some grammatical rule.

Comment: Surely a clause has to include a verb?

Comment: In this case, the verb is somewhat implied. I've gleaned from various sources "implied verbs" are acceptable, but I'm not sure. I guess I'm mostly curious about such an interjection's categorization and stratification, mostly with regards to the second example.

Comment: I really don't think it makes any difference what punctuation is used when representing speech like this. If I was writing the dialogue I would use a full stop or a dash, but the fact that a comma is used here doesn't imply any different relationship between the salutation and the introduction.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not asking whether or not it makes a difference. I'm curious about the theory behind it.